# logstash-input-mongodb loop on a "restarting error" - Timestamp

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I try to use the mongodb plugin as input for logstash.
Here is my simple configuration:

```
input {
    mongodb {
        uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB'
        placeholder_db_dir => '/Users/TEST/Documents/WORK/ELK_Stack/LogStash/data/'
        collection => 'logCollection_ALL'
        batch_size => 50
    }
}
filter {}
output { stdout {} }
```

But I'm facing a "loop issue" probably due to a field "timestamp" but I don't know what to do.

> [2018-04-25T12:01:35,998][WARN ][logstash.inputs.mongodb  ] MongoDB Input threw an exception, restarting {:exception=>#TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected LogStash::Timestamp)>}

With also a DEBUG log:

> [2018-04-25T12:01:34.893000 #2900] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | QUERY | namespace=testDB.logCollection_ALL selector={:_id=>{:$gt=>BSON::ObjectId('5ae04f5917e7979b0a000001')}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=50 skip=0 project=nil |
>   runtime: 39.0000ms

How can I parametrize my logstash config to get my output in the stdout console ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, are you able to resolve it?

Comment: I didn't solve my problem sorry, I wanted to use mongodb input to put in series mongodb database and then elasticsearch. As I haven't resolve my problem I did this workflow in one logstash with condition on outpuf part.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of field `@timestamp` that has `ISODate` data type.

You must remove this field from all documents.

```
db.getCollection('collection1').update({}, {$unset: {"@timestamp": 1}}, {multi: true})
```